# Linked Excel Object in Powerpoint wont update when showing in slideshow

Tags: excel, object, linked-list, slideshow, powerpoint

I'm new to this and basically what I want to do is:

-I have 2 excel files and 1 powerpoint presentation
 -all of the files are in a shared network
 -I linked my excel files to the powerpoint
 -I have office 2003 and 2007 versions

The problem:

I play the slideshow of the powerpoint and set it to loop on 1 computer to display it on a big LCD at work, I then access the excel files on a separate computer and update it from there, the problem is the slideshow that is playing wont display my changes automatically. I have to manually stop the show and click the (update link) on the slides to have it show the updates I just inputted.

Is there a way so that the slideshow will display my updated data within the show and I wont have to manually stop it and click the update link.

I have found a somewhat similar question here but it was not answered to the point where it will help me advance my question.

Answer (score 1):

I've solve the problem above using this code

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = 2 Then
        ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
    End If
End Sub
```

Assuming I have 2 slides in the show, when is passes on slide 2 it will trigger the update links and loops back to slide 1 with the updated OLE links. It took me a lot of reading to get to this part but I cant get it to run when I start the show. I have to manually press alt+F8 and click run so the code will loop every slide 2.

EDIT:
Finally got it working without running the macro once. i just open the powerpoint and play the show. the updates were dynamically updated when the show passed slide 2 or just the beginning. Now there are some that still dont have solutions for this problem, hope this helps you.

I utilized the autoevent.zip found here at http://skp.mvps.org/autoevents.htm. I installed the AutoEvents.ppa included in the zip as an Add In and activated it in PPT2007 and PPT2003. and then created a normal module/macro with this code.

```
Sub Auto_ShowBegin()
ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
End Sub
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
'
' AUTO UPDATE OF OLE LINKS MACRO
'
    If SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition = 2 Then
        ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks
    End If
End Sub
```

And your done. Please make sure that you save your powerpoint in macro-enabled format both for 2003 and 2007, this is because I have two versions of ms office. and tick the ckeck box saying -Trust access to the VBA project object model. Also loop your slideshow so that when it passed the slide 2 or just the beginning of the show, it will update all OLE links.

Do comment if I have missed something.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need code for this.

Add a new class module to your presentation and name it "clsEvents".
Add this code:

```
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application

Sub PPTEvent_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
   Dim objSld As Slide, shp As Shape

   Set objSld = Wn.Presentation.Slides(Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition)

   For Each shp In objSld.Shapes
      If shp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
         shp.LinkFormat.Update
      End If
      Next shp

End Sub
```

In a normal module put:

```
Dim app As clsEvents

Sub SetUpEvents()

    Set app = New clsEvents
    Set app.PPTEvent = Application

End Sub
```

Run setupevents before starting the slideshow.