# How to update live links in PPT from Excel - while in Slideshow mode

Tags: excel, hyperlink, powerpoint, live

I have pasted (paste special, paste link) data a cell in Excel into PPT.
I update the excel data and simultaneously I can see the data change in the PPT slide (edit mode)
However, when I run the PPT slideshow:

1. the data does not update (in PPT when I update in Excel)
2. the data no longer updates, even when I return to PPT edit mode

Does anyone know if it's possible to have a live link within the PPT slideshow?
(that's not broken by running the slideshow).

[MSOffice 2010 on Win7] VBA can probably help, but I'm not a VBA programmer...
This stackoverflow.com link is very similar, but needs VBA: [Linked Excel Object in Powerpoint wont update when showing in slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662108/linked-excel-object-in-powerpoint-wont-update-when-showing-in-slideshow)

TIA

**PS Context:** This is so that I can display an ever-changing number at an auction on one screen (eg on PPT slide), when I change the data on another (eg Excel) using [dual display: laptop + TV]

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be done using VBA and a class module, as far as I'm aware. There are several potential solutions in the link you provided, but without VBA, I don't think this is possible.

Fortunately, someone else has created an add-in designed to resolve the problem you're facing. I think this may be for an earlier version of PPT, so it might not work for you, but it would be a great place to start.

You might consider trying the Add-in which can be found here:

http://skp.mvps.org/updtlinks.htm

Comment: Wonderful - this looks exactly what I need. It did not work for Office2010 - but that's probably because I could not find the 2010 equivalent of Tools >'Update links during show...'. I'll keep looking and also checking out: http://officeone.mvps.org/protools/protools_update_links.html  (seems to be a commercial update of Update Links)

Comment: Check to see if there's now an Add-Ins tab on the 2010 ribbon bar. Old-style toolbar add-ins appear there in versions 2007 and onward.  If not, check your security settings (File | Options | Trust Center | Trust Center Settings ...) to see if something's preventing the addin from loading.